# CodeIgniter - Returning multiple file upload details

Tags: codeigniter

Im using the codeigniter upload library to upload multiple files, which works fine ... What im having problems with is returning the information about the files.

Im using the following code to print the results for testing

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->upload->data()); echo '</pre>';
```

A cut down version of the results are as follows

```
Array
(
[file_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => filename1.gif
        [1] => filename2.jpg
    )
)
```

The way my view is setup, is that i use jquery to insert multiple dynamic file input fields so the amount of files can be 1, it can be 50 and so on.

Im wondering how i would loop through that array to send each filename to the database

Answer (score 0):

This would loop through the results and insert each into a table:

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
$table_name = 'files'; // change to whatever you need.
$column_name = 'file'; // change to whatever you need.

foreach ($data['file_name'] as $file_name){
  $this->db->insert($table_name, array($column_name => $file_name));
}
```